# Can't use Worker-Loader with Vuejs and Webpack

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, vue.js, webpack, web-worker

I am trying to get web workers up and running with Vue cli3 and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I want to use the following package, worker-loader (and not vue-worker), as it looks well maintained and with more contributions.

Following their tutorial I attempted to modify webpack using the vue cli as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule('worker-loader')
          .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
          .use('worker-loader')
            .loader('worker-loader')
            .end()
    }
}
```

which I hope should match their

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which can be read here (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader). I tried to follow the documentation for vue cli3 as best I could (found here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration).

My component is pretty simple:

```
import Worker from 'worker-loader!./../../sharedComponents/equations/recurringTimeComposer.js';

<...>
watch:{

 recurringPaymentReturnObj: function(newVal, oldVal){
        const myWorker = new Worker;
        myWorker.postMessage({ hellothere: 'sailor' });
        myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log('value of e from message return', e.data);
 }
}
<...>
```

and in my `./../../sharedComponents/equations/recurringTimeComposer.js` file I have:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from main script: ', e.data);
    // var workerResult = 'Result: ' + e.data;
    // console.log('Posting message back to main script');
    postMessage('hello back handsome');
    close();
}
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined a162426ab2892af040c5.worker.js:2:15
```

After some googling I came across this post: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6642, which suggests that the best way to fix this is to add the following to webpack:

```
output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
       publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000',
       globalObject: 'this'
},
```

After modifying my `vue.config.js` file I have:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
          .rule('worker-loader')
          .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
          .use('worker-loader')
            .loader('worker-loader')
            .end()
        config
            .output
            .path(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))
            .filename('bundle.js')
            .publicPath('http://localhost:8080')
            .globalObject('this')
    }
}
```

...but still I am getting the window is not defined error.

Does anyone know what is going wrong? It seems to be a weird error in webpack.

Thanks!

EDIT: oh yeah, here is the MDN page for webworker as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers.

Comment: Ah....if anyone has an answer to this question please add, but am using vue-worker for the moment as I couldn't get the other to integrate into webpack. Thanks~

Answer (score 6):

Being new to Javascript I kept coming back to this issue when trying to use web workers with VueJS. I never managed to make it work with `vue-worker` or `worker-loader`.

It is now 2020 and Google has released [worker-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin).

To use it create a module `my-worker` with two files `index.js` and `worker.js`.

`index.js` creates the module:

```js
const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', { type: 'module' });

const send = message => worker.postMessage({
  message
})

export default {
  worker,
  send
}
```

`worker.js` contains the logic:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'
addEventListener("message", async event => {
    let arrayToReverse = event.data.message.array
    let reversedArray = _.reverse(arrayToReverse)
    // Send the reversed array
    postMessage(reversedArray)
});
```

You will also need to update your `vue.config.js` to use the WorkerPlugin:

```js
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      globalObject: "this"
    },
    plugins: [
      new WorkerPlugin()
    ]
  }
};
```

Now you can use you worker in your components:

1. Import it with `import worker from '@/my-worker'`.
2. Setup a listener in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook with `worker.worker.onmessage = event => { // do something when receiving postMessage }`
3. Start the worker with `worker.send(payload)`.

I set up a starter code on [github](https://github.com/Braincoke/starter-vue-web-worker). I still haven't managed to make HMR work though...

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (note the first line):

```
config.module.rule('js').exclude.add(/\.worker\.js$/)

config.module
  .rule('worker-loader')
  .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
  .use('worker-loader')
  .loader('worker-loader')
```

The first line excludes worker.js files, so two loaders wouldn't fight over the same js file

Comment: The first line solved my problem too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need ? [Vue issue with worker-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2276)

Answer (score 0):

Updating from the classic vue & webpack config, I found out that to make this one work, I needed to deactivate parallelization.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    parallel: false,
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.module
        .rule('worker')
        .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
        .use('worker-loader')
        .loader('worker-loader')
        .end();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried add web worker to a vue-cli4 project, and here is what I found:

1. **using worker-loader and make configs in chainWebpack:**
   HMR works fine, but sourcemap broke, it show babel transformed code.
2. **using worker-plugin as @braincoke mentioned**:
   HMR broke, but sourcemap works fined. and eslint broke while suggested disable all worker js file eslint instead.

Finally, My solution is tossing vue-cli away, and embrace **vite**.It support worker natively, and all just go fine now. (I think upgrade webpack to v5 can solve this, but i never tried.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `worker-loader` is [no longer necessary](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) as of Webpack 5, what worked for me is to add the `import.meta.url` since initiating the Worker via relative URL to current file doesn't work. What works is loading the script relative to the HTML file that is executing the JS code in the app:

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker-test.js', import.meta.url));
```